# powershell regex Pattern

Tags: regex, powershell

I get different results.

In Powershell using:

```
$Matches = Select-String -InputObject (Get-Content "StevenBlackhosts-urls.txt") `
             -Pattern "(^|\.)ad[sxvkdz]\-" -AllMatches                                          #`
$Matches.Matches.Count
```

I get 12 matches and this is incorrect.

In Notepad++, find and count

```
"(^|\.)ad[sxvkdz]\-"
```

I have 62 matches and this is correct.

I do not know what's wrong?
the txt "StevenBlackhosts-urls.txt" contains 65106 lines ...

- zeus.ad.intl.xiaomi.com
- api.ad.intl.xiaomi.com
- sdkconfig.ad.intl.xiaomi.com
- adv.sec.intl.miui.com
- zeus.ad.xiaomi.com
- www.api.ad.intl.xiaomi.com
- ampmetrics.engadget.com
- c.adskeeper.co.uk
- events3.adcolony.com
- metrics.adage.com
- ads.feedly.com
- lepodownload.mediatek.com
- ads.aerserv.com
- ads.mp.mydas.mobi
- ads.nexage.com
- sdk.adincube.com
- dasdada.fu.ck
- i1.dl-ad.com
- ad.api.kaffnet.com
- ad.click.kaffnet.com
- api.ad.snappea.com
- etc..

testing in this way if I get the same result to Notepaq++; Why does this happen ??

```
$Matches = Select-String -InputObject (Get-Content "StevenBlackhosts-urls.txt") -Pattern "( |\.)ad[sxvkdz]\-" -AllMatches
$Matches.Matches.Count
```

It also works well like this, giving me the 62 lines

```
Get-Content "StevenBlackhosts-urls.txt" | Select-String -Pattern "(^|\.)ad[sxvkdz]\-" -AllMatches | set-content "test.txt"
```

Comment: Can you please share the contents of the file? At least an extract?

Comment: Ditto, please share the contents otherwise this makes it rather difficult to assist

Comment: The only real difference that I see in the pattern is the `^` anchor: in PS, it will match the start of the string, in NPP, start of a line. However, with `Select-String`, your input is processed line by line, so it is hard to guess.

Comment: Perhaps you are encountering issues because you are using the automatic `$Matches` variable. Try a different variable, and see if you get the same results.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician: It's good advice to avoid defining custom variables whose names clash with [_automatic_ variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables), but - perhaps surprisingly - defining a custom `$Matches` variable works just fine: `$matches = 'foo' | Select-String .; $Matches.Matches.Count`. As for how to avoid name collisions fundamentally: see [this discussion](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4394#issuecomment-321955860)

Comment: ... Try a different variable, and see if you get the same results. – TheMadTechnician ... it did not work; thanks for comment

Comment: Pasting in that regular expression into notepad++ with or without quotes didn't give me any matches to the regex originally posted. Tried on regexr.com too and still no bueno. Can you describe specifically what you'd like to match, perhaps a regex ninja on here can help with that information

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-Content "StevenBlackhosts-urls.txt" | Select-String -Pattern "(^|\.)ad[sxvkdz]\-" -AllMatches | Measure-Object –Line | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Lines
```

this works right for me ..
thank you all for your suggestions . .